# Ubuntu VM Capture Port

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, traffic, capture

I have been working for hours trying to figure out how to to set up a capture port on an extra Ubuntu 16.04 server port.

**Summary:**
Host machine, Windows 7, has 2 ports.  One port is for accessing the machine and the other port is for capturing traffic and is currently the destination of a port mirror on a Cisco switch.  I would like it if traffic would pass through the host port into the VM adapter 2 port so I can monitor the traffic using NTOPng.

**Problem:**
My static management port is working fine but I cannot get traffic to pass through the host port into the Ubuntu VM capture port.

**Current Setup:**

*VM Interface setup*

[image: Ubuntu VM Interface Settings]

*rc.local Settings* (To get the interface into promiscuous mode)

```
ifconfig enp0s8 promisc
```

*Interface Settings*

```
#Listening port
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet manual
```

*Current Interface Status*

```
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:99:b9:41
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe99:b941/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2078 (2.0 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)
```

**Weird Observations:**
The host port does capture packets (confirmed by wireshark) and then stops capturing packets as soon as the virtual machine is turned on.  I get a message saying that the interface is no longer available in Wireshark.

Thanks ahead of time for any help.